# C++ remove by index a value within a vector of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I'm trying to allow my code structure to just add and remove `SDL_Textures*` so that I don't have to manually add an offset or draw it, rather it all handled by my class `Screen_Object`. My declaration is `std::vector < SDL_Texture* > m_Textures;`. I have this other method that allows me to alter the `std::vector` but it won't compile:

```
void Screen_Object::Remove_Texture(SDL_Texture* p_Texture)
{
    for (unsigned int i=0; i < m_Textures.size(); i++)
    {
        if (m_Textures[i] == p_Texture)
        {
            m_Textures.erase(i,    1 );
            m_Texture_Rects.erase(i,    1 );
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the definitions btw:

```
std::vector < SDL_Texture* > m_Textures;
std::vector < SDL_Rect* > m_Texture_Rects;
```

Error message:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<SDL_Texture*>::erase(unsigned int&, int)'
```

Comment: One question per stackoverflow.com question, please. You are asking two completely different questions that have nothing to do with each other, whatsoever.

Comment: Ah okay that last part makes sense about the ```const```. I'm not quite sure I understand the first part about erase though, as in "convert a vector's index to an equivalent iterator"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
m_Textures.erase(i,    1 );
m_Texture_Rects.erase(i,    1 );
```

to:

```
m_Textures.erase(m_Textures.begin() + i);
m_Texture_Rects.erase(m_Texture_Rects.begin() + i);
```

`erase` expects an iterator, not an integer.

Comment: great! that worked. Just for future reference, how can I erase more than 1 element in this way?

Comment: `m_Textures.erase(m_Textures.begin() + i, m_Textures.begin() + i + number_of_elements);`